# Problem with the bibunits

Tags: bibtex, bibunits

I have a problem with compiling bibunits. Even the most easy example (quite similar to the one published in the official documentation for this package) does not work:

```
\documentclass[english,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage{bibunits}

\begin{document}

\begin{bibunit}[plain]
I want to cite two works, the first one~\cite{Dub1} and the second one~\cite{Dub2}. 
\putbib[mybib]
\end{bibunit}

\begin{bibunit}[alpha]
I want to cite only work, that is~\cite{Har}. 
\putbib[mybib]
\end{bibunit}

\end{document}
```

There are 3 errors:

```
I found no \citation commands---while reading file bibunittest1.aux
I found no \bibdata command---while reading file bibunittest1.aux
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file bibunittest1.aux
```

Also, if I want to do something like that:

```
\documentclass[english,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

I want to cite two works, the first one~\cite{Dub1} and the second one~\cite{Dub2}. 
I want to cite only work, that is~\cite{Har}.

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{mybib}

\end{document}
```

so, without using the package, all is good. I will be very thankful for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Pardon my english. I'm not a native speaker.

To compile your document you need to run 5 different processes (see documentation of `bibunits`, page 2): latex bibunittest1, bibtex bu1, bibtex bu2, latex bibunittest1, latex bibunittest1 . I use TeXMaker and I used QuickBuild Wisard (clicking consecutively LaTeX, BiBTeX, BiBTeX, LaTeX, LaTeX) to produce following string:

```
latex -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex|bibtex %|bibtex %|latex -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex|latex -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
```

Then I manually replaced two percent signs with `bu1` and `bu2`:

```
latex -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex|bibtex bu1|bibtex bu2|latex -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex|latex -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
```

This command has successfully produced a `.dvi` file.